# How can I check field exist or not in mongo db before querying to mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have to run a dynamic query on collections in such a way that user enters collection name, field name and field value and I have to first of all check whether the field name supplied by user exists in the collection , if not then I have to run another query as shown in the example below.

For example:
If user enters collection name `user`, field name is `type` and field value is `article`. And based on parameters I have to query as follows:

1) If `type` field exists in collection `user`,  my query will be:

```
query = user.find({type:'article'})
```

2) If type is not field of collection `user`, my query will be:

```
query = user.find()
```

I tried `$exists` but it is not working for me. And how can I use `$exists` before querying? because my collection, field name and field value all are dynamic.
And How can I check that `type` field exists or not in `user` collection?

I already tried the solution with `$exists`, but I want to know if there is another way to do it.

Comment: Which mongodb driver are you using for node.js?

Comment: With this design you will very likely run into performance problems. When you want to know if the field exists *anywhere* in the collection, you either need to perform a full-collection scan or use an index. But when you don't know your field names in advance, you can't create an index for every possible field. That means each of your queries will have linear performance to number of entries in the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Philipp mentioned in his comment, you are bound to bump into performance issues as you would need to perform a full-collection scan without the use of indexes. Using [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/), the query will return fields also equal to null. Suppose you want to first find all records who have the field `type` set and isn't null, then use a combination of the [**`$ne`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator. The closest you could try is get the count of that field and then determine the query object based on the field count:

```
var type_count = db.user.find({"type": {$exists: true, $ne: null}}).count();
var query = (type_count > 0) ? {"type": "article"} : {};
db.user.find(query);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have one doubt, Can I use this solution in mongoose without callback?

Comment: This was just an example in the shell. In mongoose, you will of course need to add the `exec` function with the callback e.g. `db.user.find(query).exec(function (err, users){ ... });`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I thought it would be great if I can avoid callback.